# Which difference between declaration methods of controls

Tags: c#, wpf, controls

Just faced with different declaration of WPF controls; in particular "Button".
So could someone shed light on this matter?

First variant:

```
<Button x:Name="button1"/>
```

Second variant:

```
<Button>button1</Button>
```

Both are working.

Comment: button Name and Content are very different. these two example are doing different things

Comment: The second one is equivalent to `<Button Content="button1"/>`, because there is the `[System.Windows.Markup.ContentProperty("Content")]` attribute on the ContentControl class declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The first one names the control instance without setting its content, the second one sets its content without giving the instance a name.

Comment: that is not strictly true for all types, only for Button. `<tag>something</tag>` can perform different operations, not only assigning Content. e.g. `<TextBlock>hello</TextBlock>` assigns Text property. `<sys:string>hello</sys:string>` declares a string